# Installing RealVNC armhf version on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 (arm64) on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: dpkg, vnc, mate, raspberrypi

I'm trying to get VNC running on the above and I'll try and quickly run down how I managed to get to the position where it's *almost* working.

So I installed the arm64 image from [RealVNC download](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/) and then obviously got this error as I'm running the arm64 Ubuntu Mate and RealVNC only offer an armhf one:

```
error wrong architecture - run dpkg --add-architechture to add it and update afterwards
```

So I forced the architecture by running:

```
 sudo dpkg --add-architechture armhf
```

When I ran vncserver it kept complaining that some files of `/usr/lib` were missing, so I copied a load of them from this [Github backup here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/lib) to `usr/lib` and that seemed to allow vncserver to run.

Yes I know this is not the best method, but it seems Ubuntu Mate is still in beta. Anyway, vnc setup a password, key, etc. and gave me my local IP and a session number/port. When logging into it it asks for the username/password, waits a few seconds and then returns 'access is denied'.
I should note that when running the `xstartup.sh` script in `/home/user/.vnc` it used to say `cannot find /home/user/.Xresources` file. I did notice that error appears here in [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04) yet it's not mentioned as an issue?

I think I ran `touch ~/.Xresources` which made that error go away, but when I run the `xstartup.sh` it just leads to a blank terminal window.

The last two log files are here: [Pastebin1](https://pastebin.com/HW3THBcC) & [Pastebin2](https://pastebin.com/zrHw1i9s). The second is the only one that shows the client being rejected. So, in short I think the VNC login errors are something to do with the frontend desktop environment rather than forcing the architecture / copying over files.

Any ideas at all please? How do I fix the desktop environment to allow the VNC connection?

Comment: you can use x11vnc or tightvnc.

Comment: You can have a look at this thread:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=288769 He also made a YouTube video about it, with all the commands on description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxey8eKi9bE